# simple algorithm to crack 4 number password in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I just can't get my head around an algorithm which I initially thought would be relatively simple.

Basically, a user enters a 4 length number combination(0 - 9) and I want an algorithm that will try every possible combination until it matches that of what the user entered.

As I said it's probably quite simple with nested loops or something but I just can't get my head around it.

Appreciate any help. I'm using delphi by the way.

Comment: well, there's 10^4 possible combinations...I would personally try setting up an array of zeros n[i] and have 4 nested loops with separate index variables...if I knew anything about delphi, maybe i'd draw a picture...sounds like a rather odd need

Comment: Grover algorithm is the best. :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm

Comment: `I just can't get my head around it` - iirc this was a popular pop song in 2001?

Answer (score 6):

The question appears to ask how to generate all 4 digit strings using the digits `'0'` to `'9'`.

You can do this readily with a `for` loop and a call to `Format`:

```
for i := 0 to 9999 do
  str := Format('%.4d', [i]);
```

The precision specifier in the format string ensures that the string will be zero-padded.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i := 1 to 9999 do
  TryCombo(i);
```

There is no need to do nested loops. If you need them in character form, it's easier to just use IntToStr than just use combinations and nested loops. If it must be padded then use a simple pad loop:

```
  s:= inttostr(i);
  while length(s) < 4 do
    s := '0' + s;
```

Comment: The pad loop is sub-optimal. Replace the while-loop with `if Length(s) < 4 then s := Copy('0000',1,4-Length(s)) + s;` or use an appropriate `Format()` call instead of `IntToStr()`

Comment: Yes and no. While loopy loop is less than optimal on large loops, simple software tends to be different:

Code:
  for i := 0 to 1000000 do // million
    begin
      s := IntToStr(i);
      while Length(s)<4 do
        s := '0' + S;
    end;

versus

  for i := 0 to 1000000 do
    s := Format('%.4d', [i]);

And timed to high precision timers gives me:
One million IntToStr: 0.0728s
One million Format: 0.1045s

on my i7.

Replace 4 figure format with 7 and they are about the same. On 11 character pad, Format edges ahead. So, you know, depends.

Answer (score 3):

While @Simpson Bart answer is the quickest solution for your specific problem I have a feeling that you might be a Computer Science student and you have been given this task as homework.

If that is the case I asume your teacher/proffesor probably wants to see you implement a custom counter with which you will test all posible combinations untill you find the corect one.
In case of finding passwords this way this is called a brute force attack.

So how you do this?

First think about math and the use of different numeral systems. Why? Becouse in order to implement custom counter you actually have to create custom numeral system. And the base number of your numeral system is the number of posible characters that can be used in password. In your case that is 10 (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).

Second thing you have to do is create a string containing all posible characters. We use this later for reading specific characters by finding them by their index which is position in string.

Then you simply count up in your new numeral system and generate posible password by assigning specific characters from strings containing all posible characters. You do this by reading specific character whose position is determined by value of specific digit in your numeral system.

And finally you test to see if the generated password is the same as the one you are seeking.

I hope my explanation of how you should approach to this problem is understandable enough since I'm not natively English speaking person so it is posible that I haven't expressed myself in best way.

If not I'm also posting a code example below with comments which might be more understandable.

```
const
  //String containing all possible lower case leters and numbers of english alphabet
  CPossibleLowercaseLetersNumbersChars: AnsiString = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz';
  //String containing all possible chars used in HexDecimal numeral system
  CPossibleHexChars: AnsiString = '0123456789abcdef';

implementation

function BruteForcePasswordFinder(InputStr: AnsiString; PossibleChars: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4: Integer; //Could use Byte (integer from 0 to 255) instead
    //String for temporary storing password string we generate
    TempPassString: AnsiString;
begin
  //Set initial conditions
  Num1 := 0;
  Num2 := 0;
  Num3 := 0;
  Num4 := 0;
  Result := '';
  //Check to see if password is all zeros
  //First set the legth of temporary password string to have the same number of characters
  //as possible password
  SetLength(TempPassString,4);
  //Set each character of the temporary password string.
  //We read the characters from an array storing all posible hcaracters by specifying characters
  //index position in that array
  //NOTE Unless you are using newer versions of Delphi and compiling for Android first character
  //in string has index of 1 so we have to add 1 to the Num1, Num2, Num3, Num4 value
  TempPassString[1] := PossibleChars[Num1+1];
  TempPassString[2] := PossibleChars[Num2+1];
  TempPassString[3] := PossibleChars[Num3+1];
  TempPassString[4] := PossibleChars[Num4+1];
  //Check to see if temporary password string matches with the imput password string
  if TempPassString = InputStr then
  begin
    //Set result to matching code
    Result := TempPassString;
    //Use Exit call to prematurely end the function so we don't waste time testing
    //all remaining password combinations
    Exit;
  end;
  //Custom counter implementation
  while Result = '' do
  begin
    //Increase the last number count by one
    Num4 := Num4+1;
    //Check to see if the Num4 is greater than specific base number
    //Base number is number of posible digit representations
    //- 0 and 1 in Binary numeral system
    //- 0 to 9 in Decimal numeral system
    //- 0 to 9 and A B C D E F in HexDecimal numeral system
    //In our case base number is the number of posible characters (Lenght of PossibleChars)
    //If it is increase the Num3 and set Num4 to 0 just like you increase tens in Decimal
    //numeral sytem and stes ones back to 0
    if Num4 > Length(PossibleChars) then
    begin
      Num4 := 0;
      Num3 := Num3+1;
      //Check to see if Num3 is greater than specific base number
      //If it is increase the Num2 by 1 and set Num3 back to 0
      if Num3 > Length(PossibleChars) then
      begin
        Num3 := 0;
        Num2 := Num2+1;
        //Check to see if Num2 is greater than specific base number
        //If it is increase the Num1 by 1 and set Num2 back to 0
        if Num2 > Length(PossibleChars) then
        begin
          Num2 := 0;
          Num1 := Num1+1;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    //Prepare temp password string for comparison
    TempPassString[1] := PossibleChars[Num1+1];
    TempPassString[2] := PossibleChars[Num2+1];
    TempPassString[3] := PossibleChars[Num3+1];
    TempPassString[4] := PossibleChars[Num4+1];
    //Check to see if temporary password string matches with the imput password string
    if TempPassString = InputStr then
    begin
      //Set result to matching code
      Result := TempPassString;
      //Use Exit call to prematurely end the function so we don't waste time testing
      //all remaining password combinations
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Usage example

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var FoundPassword: String;
begin
  FoundPassword := BruteForcePasswordFinder('59dg',CPossibleLowercaseLetersNumbersChars);
  ShowMessage('Found password is: '+FoundPassword);
end;
```

DISCLAIMER: The reason why I put my code into a funtion which returns found code as String result is becouse in actual scenario you probably would not be able to test your password gues against actual password (othervise there would be no need for all this) but you would probably be checking if feeding the guesed password to some other algorithm (MD5 hash algorithm for instance) would generate same result as your imput data is (most servers store passwords as hash representations and thus preventing even server owners to see what password is actually stored).

Comment: Donwvoter could you please explain why you downvoted my answer.

Comment: I did, because the solution you have proposed in your answer is extremely complicated for the task to be completed. The asker should recognise that the solution is elementary: one single loop which produces 10k possible permutations. Your solution easily confuses and misleads somebody without the basic knowledge required to perform such a simple task. (Oh, and I have tried to explain it in a comment at the time, but somehow the engine have not send it.)

Comment: @SilverWarrior - The commenting system did not let me to address you for some reason. I only want you to be notified of my answer.

Comment: @mg30rg If you look at my answer again you will see that I ackowledge the Simpson Bart answer as the quieckest solution. My answer was considered as an alternate solution. And as I stated in my answer the reason why I posted it here is becouse I belive that the OP's teacher/proffesor wants something more from him than just using simple while loop. The reason which made me to belive this is that the OP itself has mentioned the use of nested lops so I asume they are learning about code nesting. So I don't belive that I earn the downvote for this.

Comment: Yes, you acknowledged that there is an actual answer to the question, but you thought you should provide an unnecessarily complex solution instead based upon a guess backed only a hint about some sort of nested loops (as if nested loops are required here). Also when it comes to memory, code speed or source code size your solution is inefficient. You have optimized your code for "prettiness" based on some impression. That is also a reason why I have downvoted it.

Comment: @SilverWarrior - The commenting system did not let me to address you for some reason. I only want you to be notified of my answer

Comment: @mg30rg It is true that code in my answer isn't best optimized but as you can see it also supports finding out the passwords which also includes letters and not only numbers and it alows you to specify which are posible characters. Now you can't achieve that using the optimized approach. Can you?

Comment: Not with the marginally optimized approach. But it is not a problem since that was not a requirement for this task.

Comment: True that this wasn't originally demanded in the question but it is generally better to write your code in such a way that it can be easily extended when needed. And since the days of when we only had numerical passwords are already gone I asumed that next step would be to also support passwords with letters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62675/discussion-between-mg30rg-and-silverwarior).

Comment: Or let's not. Since Stack Overflow is not in its best shape today. So IMHO putting non-necessary "futureproof" code into your codebase only leads to harder testing, more (therefore harder to read) source code and maintenance difficulties. The program should only know the "sufficient and necessary".

Comment: @mg30rg I rather have a few hundreds lines more of so called "futureproof" code as you refer to it rather than completly rewriting part of existing code sometime in the future becouse it doesen't aprovide me a chace to expand its functionality. Especially since I already know now that there is a large chance that I will have to expand my code in the future. Some planning ahead doesen't hurt. As far as rewriting existing code goes I have a whole lot of expirience with this. In one of my projects there isn't a part of code that hasn't been compleetly rewriten athleast three tiems already.

Comment: Ever since I'm developing commercial software I follow the _"necessary and sufficient"_ principle. My code elements (_objects/modules/etc_) never do less than necessary or more than sufficient for the required task. Some times I feel tempted to provide functionality that is not yet needed (but I _suspect_ to be needed in the future), but in cases like that I recall a horroristic case from my early developer days: (to be continued)

Comment: I was working with an instance of a (custom) component which was used for years at that company and said to be reliable. It performed fine on all unit tests was used widely in multiple projects and so on. So I used it bravely... and it broke my code. I was debugging that code for literally days to find the problem, which was in a setter method of a property which happened to be **practically** read-only in all earlier code. (to be continued)

Comment: In fact it was not read only... it had a setter property only it was written when the first version of the component was created (the original developer wanted his code to be future proof and _assumed_ it will be needed later) and was not modified since then (since noone needed a setter/to set that property) so by that time it was **conceptually wrong**.

Comment: If I understand you correctly the original author of that component made a mistake of actually implementing a setter method for certain property even thou it wasn't needed. Now this is not what I'm recomending. I'm recomending of writing a code in a way so that it alows you to write a setter method if needed and not write it right away. In practice this would mean that I would chose to store some informtion in a class rather than in plain old record as class alows me to implement a setter method for certain prperty in future. It doesen't mean I will do it right away.

Comment: Refactoring code is easy. Don't design complexity that you aren't using. It won't be tested properly, or if it is it will be expensive. If you work for me and design code that meets requirements that don't exist, and write code that never runs, you are in trouble.

Comment: @SilverWarior - Aside from the case I've mentioned (where we are talking about a data access layer object, not some structured memory block), using a _record_ is not really an alternative of using a _class_, and not only because the _setter/getters_. A _class is a reference type_, while the _record is a value type_. They are **not even playing in the same league**, so your example is wrong. :) Also what you are proposing is to add _unnecessary complexity_ to the code which multiplies its size instead of writing a 2 line long code which can be replaced with _no regrets_ if it becomes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Delphi XE7 you can use the new Parallel Programming Library to run the algorithm with more threads, using [TParallel.For](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Threading.TParallel.For):

```
TParallel.For (lowerBound, upperBound, Method);
```

An example is shown at http://www.fmxexpress.com/fast-threaded-parallel-for-loop-in-delphi-xe7-firemonkey-on-android-ios-windows-and-osx/

```
TParallel.For(1, Max, procedure(I: Integer)
  begin
    if TryCode(I) then
    begin
      WriteLn(I); 
    end
  end);
```

However I see no way to terminate parallel processing conditionally.

Comment: Nice answer but do I have to point out that it points ways out the era of the original question?

Comment: @mg30rg Definitely Yes